# Getting an input's current value in a keypress event in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add a dirty class to an input while the user is typing. I'v created a directive that binds to the `keydown` event and checks the value against the last saved one.

```
elm.bind('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) 
      scope.update();

    else if ( scope.last_saved_value !== elm.val() )
        elm.addClass('dirty-input');
});
```

[JSBIN full example](http://jsbin.com/rexazigi/1/edit)

To see the problem, change the value in the input and press enter. This works fine. Now, add another number and you'll see that the field does not become dirty and that the event is capturing the previous value and not the current. My guess is that `elm.val()` \ `model.$viewValue` are being updated only after the event is taken care of (to allow manipulation on the value).

So how can I capture the current value on `keydown` ?

Comment: try `scope.update()` in `scope.$apply(function() {scope.update()})`. Also look at form validations supported by angularjs. It automatically adds some classes.http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: `scope.update` is executing `fn` in `scope$apply` - The problem is that i dont get the recent value in the event.